# Spring Boot @Component annotation not used on interface but still bean is being provided with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

I am a new learner of Spring Boot. As far as I learned by now, we need to use `@Component` above a class/interface for Spring to store the bean in the Spring container. And we can inject that bean by using `@Autowired`. I've been working on a demo project where I can't see `@Component` on an interface but somehow the bean of that interface is being provided correctly. If I add `@Component` it says multiple beans found.

Post Controller Class:

```
package com.ashik.jobmarket.controller;

import com.ashik.jobmarket.repository.PostRepository;
import com.ashik.jobmarket.model.Post;
import com.ashik.jobmarket.repository.SearchRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    PostRepository repo;
    @Autowired
    SearchRepository srepo;

    @GetMapping("/allPosts")
    @CrossOrigin
    public List<Post> getAllPosts(){
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/posts/{text}")
    @CrossOrigin
    public List<Post> search(@PathVariable String text){
        return srepo.findByText(text);
    }


    @PostMapping("/post")
    @CrossOrigin
    public Post addPost(@RequestBody Post post){
        return repo.save(post);
    }

}
```

The Post Repository Interface:

```
package com.ashik.jobmarket.repository;
import com.ashik.jobmarket.model.Post;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface PostRepository extends MongoRepository<Post, String>{}
```

***No Class implemented Post Repository.***

I tried adding `@Component` myself but it's saying that I have multiple beans of the same name. I am trying to understand the process, and how the bean is being delivered without `@Component` annotation.

Comment: No class implements that interface. Let's start with why you think it's useful to autowire a non-existing implementation?

Comment: I am a bit confused about that as well but I think MongoRepository contains some functionalities that I needed in the project. (For example MongoClient, MongoConverter). I created an empty interface that implements the mongo interface. If I am doing things wrong can you kindly help me visualize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot uses `@EnableJpaRepositories` which all interfaces/classes that extend/implement a spring data [repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html). In turn spring then provides an implementation which is added to the container.

As [MongoRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository.html) is spring JPA repository, the extending interfaces are being picked up and provided as autowireable dependencies. So when you annotate your `PostRepository` with `@Component` it is picked up twice by spring, causing the multiple beans found exception.

For more info on this topic check [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa) and [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)